# Activate solution is disabled for provider hosted app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I have a problem with a provider hosted app that I am developing for Sharepoint 2013 (Office 365). After I upload the app to Sharepoint I can´t activate it. The button in the ribbon is disabled.

I had no problems running the app trough visual studio debugger with the web application hosted locally. The problem came when I had to move the web application to Azure so others than me could test it. I am using publish to upload the web app to Azure and to create the package for Sharepoint. I have also created a client id and secret to connect the both apps. But after uploading the Sharepoint app I can´t activate it.

I would be very thankful if anyone have an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. I turned out that I was trying to upload the app at the wrong place (**Solutions instead of apps**).